# My script works properly on Chrome, but not on Safari

Tags: javascript, django, safari

The following script is the code for a dark mode toggle on my website.

I don't really know Javascript (I only know Python), so writing this code was a challenge and it might be poorly written. But what it does is it checks for a session variable "`is_dark_mode`" using Django Templating Language, to check if the current user has previously set his view to light or dark mode, and then it proceeds to switch the Boolean for that variable and adds or removes a "`dark-mode`" class to the body of my HTML (which is how I'm switching styles when in dark mode).

It works fine in Chrome, but it doesn't work at all in Safari, and I don't know why. When using the JavaScript console, it throws an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'
```

This SyntaxError is pointing to this line of code:

```
var darkMode = ;
```

Could someone give me a hand in figuring this out? I'm learning backend only, so I got no idea of how to solve this, and I've already tried googling it, with no success.

```
<script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var modeToggle = document.getElementById("modeToggle");

        function setInitialDarkMode() {
          var darkMode = {{ request.session.is_dark_mode|default_if_none:"false"|lower }};
          modeToggle.checked = darkMode;

          if (darkMode) {
            document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
          }
        }

        modeToggle.addEventListener("change", function () {
          var darkMode = modeToggle.checked;

          fetch("{% url 'toggle-mode' %}", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ dark_mode: darkMode }),
          })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
              if (darkMode) {
                document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
              } else {
                document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
              }
              console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
        });

        setInitialDarkMode();

      });
</script>
```

Comment: Look at the generated source and see what the template code is spitting out.

Comment: @Alex `var darkMode = "{{ request.session.is_dark_mode|default_if_none:'false'|lower }}";`

Comment: @epascarello I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean or how to do that.

Comment: @AfzalK. Isn't that the code I've already got in my script?

Comment: @Alex copy paste it and try

Comment: @AfzalK. You managed to get Safari to respond to my script, which is more than I could. Thanks for that. But it's not working properly. Now, for some reason, it defaults back to True, so when I reload the page or if I go to a different page in the website, it switches back to dark mode. Both in Chrome and in Safari, so you managed to get the same result from both, that's awesome.

Comment: can you give a screenshot of the output code?

Comment: or modify it a bit like

`function setInitialDarkMode() { var darkMode = "{{ request.session.is_dark_mode|default_if_none:"false"|lower|default:"false" }}"; if (darkMode === "true") { modeToggle.checked = true; document.body.classList.add("dark-mode"); } else { modeToggle.checked = false; document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode"); } }`

Comment: This modified function worked!!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @AfzalK. Forgot to tag you in my previous comment. If there's anything I can do to reward your correct answer, please, let me know. Again, thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @Alex glad it worked, did you try the other one ? if it worked, cause not possible to test so potential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another way of doing the same as mentioned earlier

```
function checkSessionVariable() {
  var darkMode = "{{ request.session.is_dark_mode|default_if_none:"false"|lower|default:"false" }}";
  if (darkMode === "true") {
    // for calling setInitialDarkMode() or setting the toggle to true
    setInitialDarkMode();
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var modeToggle = document.getElementById("modeToggle");
  
  // Calling checkSessionVariable() function on page load
  checkSessionVariable();
  
  // put all other code

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue in your code is related to how you are initializing the `darkMode` variable. The error you are seeing, "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'", is because you have this line:

```js
var darkMode = ;
```

The variable `darkMode` is being initialized without a value, and that's causing a syntax error. To fix this issue, you should remove the line:

```js
var darkMode = ;
```

Instead, you should set the `darkMode` variable inside the `setInitialDarkMode` function using the value from your Django template. Your code should look like this:

```js
function setInitialDarkMode() {
  var darkMode = {{ request.session.is_dark_mode|default_if_none:"false"|lower }};
  modeToggle.checked = darkMode;

  if (darkMode) {
    document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
  }
}
```

This code correctly initializes the `darkMode` variable based on the value from your Django template. Make sure you don't have any extraneous characters or missing values in your Django template variable `{{ request.session.is_dark_mode|default_if_none:"false"|lower }}`, as it should provide a valid JavaScript boolean value (either `true` or `false`) for this code to work correctly.

Once you make this change, your code should work as expected in Safari and other browsers.

Comment: If I'm not missing something, your solution is exactly what I already had in my code, isn't it? That empty darkMode variable is what Safari is showing me, but that's not my code. In my code, as you can see in the original post, I did exactly as you told me to do. But thanks for the response, anyway!